# voyager-ingress in kubernetes - tls config

Tags: http, tls, kubernetes

I have a config yaml for voyager-ingress in kubernetes like this:

```
apiVersion: voyager.appscode.com/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.appscode.com/type: LoadBalancer
    ingress.appscode.com/load-balancer-ip: "88.88.88.88"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls-server-cert
    hosts:
      - "sub1.example.com"
      - "sub2.example.com"
      - "sub3.example.com"
  rules:
  - host: "sub1.example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp
          servicePort: '80'
```

I am creating the cert in another yaml. BUT the problem is that the voyager will not expose nothing on port 80 because the tls-server-cert is missing (as is configured in tls section).   So creating of the cert is refused.

i have to cretae voyager just for  80  port without the tls: section

then  create cert in yaml - cert generated

then add tls: section to config yaml.

Is this correct  process ? or it should works everything automaticaly

J@ke